# Apple Mail randomly refreshes e-mail list

Tags: mail.app

I am running Monterey (12.3.1) on a Mid-2015 MacBook Pro. Since upgrading to Monterey, the Apple Mail list of e-mails periodically (and apparently randomly) refreshes itself. This is highly annoying as it often de-selects the e-mail that I am currently reading, making it difficult to use the keyboard to make it through my e-mails. It is also **quite** visibly irritating as it probably happens 20-40 times in my 3 or so hours of e-mail use per day.

I haven't found a way to force it to happen, but it seems to happen most often when adding or removing flags, but can also happen when I am just reading an e-mail. There is usually some sort of action involved when it happens (I don't see it happen when Mail is in the background, but I'm also not always looking.)

I managed to get the following video of it happening (the video is very narrow so that my e-mail contents would not be displayed. The entire visible list is refreshing.) Here is the animated GIF:

[image: GIF showing random reload of Apple Mail inbox]

Here is the YouTube video:
https://youtube.com/shorts/kOmwczMXnsM?feature=share

In this case I was flagging some selected e-mails (out of the view of the video) when it refreshed. I am in "All inboxes" view and have 6 separate e-mail accounts that are set up in mail showing up in All inboxes. I have also noticed the behavior when in the "Flagged" smart box so it is not limited to All inboxes.

My question is this: How can I stop this behavior?!?! It's driving me nuts.

Comment: First please try updating to macOS 12.3.1 and then let us know if this persists.

Comment: Thanks ... it was a slaps head moment that I didn't update before asking! I upgraded and still notice the problem, so I edited the post with the updated version number.

Comment: i'm on macOS 12.4 and it's still happening to me too. drives me crazy! it started for me some time around early 2022.